# Enabling TLS 1.2 without changing code in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2, smtpclient, .net-4.8

I have .NET 4.5.2 application that is using `SmtpClient` to send emails. The application is installed on Windows 2012 R2 server. When I disable TLS 1 and TLS 1.1 and enable only TLS 1.2, the application stops sending mails. I think that's because .NET 4.5.2 does not support v1.2.

I am thinking of the following steps

1>Disable TLS 1 and TLS 1.1 and enable only TLS 1.2 on Windows Server.
2>Install .NET 4.8 on Windows Server.
3>Change target framework of the application to 4.8 (in csproj and web.config) and recompile.
4>Deploy application.

**Questions**
Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) `Starting with .NET Framework 4.7.1, WCF defaults to the operating system configured version`
1>Is this true only for WCF or will SMTP also defaults to operating system configured version?
2>or do I need to set version explicitly like `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
3>Is it possible to set the version TLS 1.2 right now, and when in future TLS 1.3 is available app should automatically defaults to TLS 1.3? (Without changing the code again)

Comment: I hope your app is not hosted in an Azure App Service; If you do, you can easily navigate to your App Service > Settings > TLS/SSL Settings > Upgrade to TLS 1.2 or preferred. Ideally, the highest TLS is good and secure.

Answer (score 17):

> Is this true only for WCF or will SMTP also defaults to operating system configured version?

No, [this applies to all .NET Framework networking APIs that based on SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.8), which includes SMTP, as well as HTTP and FTP.

---

> or do I need to set version explicitly like System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

If you compile your app to .NET 4.7 or higher, you don't need to set a value to `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` because it will be set to `SystemDefault` which means it will inherit the default security protocols from the operating system or from any custom configurations performed by a system administrator.

---

> Is it possible to set the version TLS 1.2 right now, and when in future TLS 1.3 is available app should automatically defaults to TLS 1.3?

Yes, you just have to check if `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is set to anything else that is not `SystemDefault` (which has the value of `0` (zero) in .NET 4.7+), and in that case you can set it to TLS 1.2 to override it.

```
var securityProtocol = (int)System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;

// 0 = SystemDefault in .NET 4.7+
if (securityProtocol != 0)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```

Comment: Where should I place this code? On the controller, on the service, or in the Startup?

Comment: @ezhupa99 At the very start of your app, before executing any HTTP request

Comment: In .net winform I set this code in form constructor and it works fine. thnx